# Next js parent route component for children components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

Let's imagine we have the `admin` module that has a few pages *customize*, *settings*, *account*.
Each of these pages should have some common layout for ex. *sidebar*.

In the case of a standard React app I would do the next thing to implement this part of the app.

 
I'd create the Parent route - **admin** and would create the parent Component that would contain a *Sidebar* and an entry point for children routes. Each child routed would have its own component and the parent will render the Sidebar and an Active Child component together.
A very cool benefit of this approach - the *Sidebar* will be rendered only once while children will be dynamically changing during the user interaction.

A small example:

```
    const Customize = () => <div><h1>Customize</h1></div>;
    const Settings = () => <div><h1>Settings</h1></div>;
    const Account = () => <div><h1>Account</h1></div>

    const Sidebar = () => (
       <h2>Frontend</h2>
       <p><Link to="/admin">Admin</Link></p>
       <p><Link to="/admin/customize">Customize</Link></p>
       <p><Link to="/admin/settings">Settings</Link></p>
       <p><Link to="/admin/account">Account</Link></p>
    );
    
    const Admin= props => {
      return (
        <div>
          <Sidebar  />
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/user' component={Customize}/>
            <Route path='/user' component={Settings}/>
            <Route path='/user' component={Account}/>
          </Switch>
          <footer>Bottom</footer>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

But how can we do it in the case of Next.js? Based on their docs we need to use the File structure pattern. Eg. create an Admin page in the `pages` folder and put *Account, Customize, Settings* into this folder.
To share some layout we can use the global **_app**, **_document** templates but they are global for the whole app.

How can I create the Parent route entry component that should keep Sidebar for all its children?

I **don't want** to re-render this Sidebar during the route changes because it isn't good regarding UX

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 4):

You can create the `Layout` component with the `Sidebar`.

Your pages folder structure gonna look like this:

```
pages
  -customize
  -settings
  -account
```

and every of this pages will be wrapped by the `Layout` component like:

```
const Customize = () => (
  <Layout>
    [page content]
  </Layout>
)
```

and the `Layout` itself looks like:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => (
  <>
    <Sidebar />
    {children}
  </>
)
```

Comment: you can also use kind of global layout and pass it using `getInitialProps`. you can easy find lots of examples like this: https://dev.to/ozanbolel/layout-persistence-in-next-js-107g

Comment: Hi, @igorves. Thanks for the answer. Does it mean that the Sidebar will be re-rendered each time when the active child page will be changed?

Comment: ya, this is ssr

Comment: you can make a one route page with state if you want

Comment: also, you can create a dynamic routing

Comment: Can you, please, show an example of the dynamic routing? Maybe some link, etc. 
I'd like to avoid the Sidebar re-render every time when an active child changes.
What I've seen so far about dynamic routing (Next.js) it's about some ID in url, etc. Did you mention it or something different?

Comment: yeah, but with will rerender the sidebar

Comment: @igorves exactly