# How to add navbar to every admin page but not on shop pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to achieve navbar and sidebar on all admin pages but not on shop.
The only problem here is the shop since I put my sidebar and navbar globally. I want to make it global for only admin and not for shop.

This is my _app.js

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}
```

And this is my Layout File...

```
 <>
      <MenuBar onToggleMenu={toggleMenu} onToggleMenuCart={toggleMenuCart} />
      <div className="ui attached pushable" style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
        <Sidebar toggleMenu={toggle} />
        <AddtoCartSidebar toggleMenu={toggleCart} />
        <div className={classes}>
          <div className="mh-25 mv-20 wrap minheight">
            <div
              className="content-area"
              style={{ width: toggle ? '80%' : '100%' }}
            >
              {children}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
```

I know I can just add Navbar and Sidebar on all pages one by one but it's not a good way for me. BTW I'm using next incase you guys get confused. I have 1 folder for admin and 1 for shop. The Layout folder consists of navbar and sidebar. I'm new on next since I just started 3 days ago so I don't know that much.

EDIT: I found 1 question a bit related to mine but different in a way: [Next js parent route component for children components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169473/next-js-parent-route-component-for-children-components)

If you don't understand try reading his question so you'll understand mine a bit more. I'm not that good at explaining.

Comment: Why not just make a conditional, if you're an admin you see the navbar. If you're not, you don't see it.

Comment: yes but i dont have roles yet

Comment: also im wondering if there is if the route is /admin it will show that navbar and if its not /admin route it will not show the navbar is there anything like that? also as i said im new on next so im not knowledgable on nextjs

Comment: @Chris if theres a way to do that without roles pls give me more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOR THOSE WHO HAVE THIS PROBLEM, I figured out an answer...

If you want your page to have sidebar and navbar and if you want your other page to have no sidebar and navbar this is how you do it... If you have more shorter and better answer you guys can answer aswell :)

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
  if (router.pathname.startsWith('/admin')) {
    return (
      <>
        <Head>
          <title>DailyMart Admin</title>
        </Head>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>DailyMart Shop</title>
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}
```

As you can see here i did a conditional for only my admin to see sidebar and navbar and for my shop it will have its own navbar! Cheers!